# Powershell convert to Json is bad format

Tags: json, powershell, ansible

I am using win_shell to convert powershell output to json format, so that i can filter it later. The problem is i am getting bad Json format.

Here is the code

```
    - win_shell: |
         Get-ChildItem -Path <some_path> |
         Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
         Select-Object -First 20 | ConvertTo-Json
         register: register_results

     - debug:
         var: register_results
```

The stdout lines i am getting is not clean to be used in a json filter:

```
  "stderr": "",
  "rc": 0,
  "stdout_lines": [
      "[",
      "    {",
      "        \"Name\":  \"976\",",
      "  \"FullName\"\"F:\\\\some\\\\path\\\\to\\\\folder\\\\976\",",
      "  \"Parent\":  {",
      "                       \"Name\":  \"first\",",
      "                       \"Parent\":  \"All\",",
      "                       \"Exists\":  true,",
      "                       \"Root\":  \"F:\\\\\",",
      "                       \"Extension\":  \"\",",
      etc...
```

Those extra whitespaces cause errors when i try to filter for example "parent" or "Name". Looks like there must be other parameter beside "ConvertToJson"to get the output cleaner.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: This post seems to also be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789365/prettify-json-in-powershell-3.

Comment: If you're just looking for single-line, no-extra-whitespace output, use `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell JSON adding value formate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826637/powershell-json-adding-value-formate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- What **`ConvertTo-Json`** outputs isn't *bad* JSON, it is ***pretty-printed* JSON**:

  - Pretty-printed JSON uses *multi-line* output with *whitespace-based indentation* for better readability.
  - Pretty-printed JSON is **still valid JSON**, however, and any JSON parser should recognize it.
- You can ***opt out* of this pretty-printing with the `-Compress` switch**, for a more efficient, but less readable representation:

  - You'll get a *single-line* output string (even for multiple inputs), with *no extraneous whitespace*.

**The output you're showing shows the pretty-printed JSON string *embedded inside another JSON string***, as a string *property value* (hence the escaping of the embedded `"` as `\"`).

Therefore, in order to process such embedded JSON, you must:

- parse the *containing* JSON
- get the value of the property that contains the *embedded* JSON (`<parsedContainingJson>.stdout_lines`)
- then parse that.

Given that whatever produces the containing JSON broke the multi-line `ConvertTo-Json` output string into an *array of lines* (as also suggested by property name `stdout_lines`), you'd first have to join the array elements back into a single string before processing them as JSON.

If you want to avoid that step, use `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this post](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2736), the JSON formatting for `ConvertTo-Json` is planned to be improved in PowerShell 6. You can override the formatting yourself after `ConvertTo-Json` like the post suggests. Some code from the post mentioned to potentially solve your issue:

```
# Formats JSON in a nicer format than the built-in ConvertTo-Json does.
function Format-Json([Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)][String] $json) {
  $indent = 0;
  ($json -Split '\n' |
    % {
      if ($_ -match '[\}\]]') {
        # This line contains  ] or }, decrement the indentation level
        $indent--
      }
      $line = (' ' * $indent * 2) + $_.TrimStart().Replace(':  ', ': ')
      if ($_ -match '[\{\[]') {
        # This line contains [ or {, increment the indentation level
        $indent++
      }
      $line
  }) -Join "`n"
}

$obj = @{}
$json = $obj | ConvertTo-Json | Format-Json
```

Alternatively, you should be able to use `ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft` or [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) directly by installing and importing the module and use that instead of `ConvertTo-Json`...

```
Install-Module Newtonsoft.Json
Import-Module Newtonsoft.Json

$obj = @{}
$json = $obj | ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft

# or Newtonsoft.Json directly (same code)

$obj = @{}
$json = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject($obj, [Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting]::Indented)
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's improved in v6 and later.  I switched to Powershell Core and it was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Outputting it to a file ought to make it easier to read back in correctly rather than trying to copy for the host output. It really depends on what language you are trying to use to filter on later.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <some_path> |
         Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
         Select-Object -First 20 | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File C:\Some\Where\Awesome\OutputJson.json
```

You could also export it to clixml if you are going to use PowerShell to do the filtering. That will help PowerShell pull it in as a recognizable PS object.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Scripts" |
         Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
         Select-Object -First 20 | Export-Clixml C:\Some\Where\Awesome\Exported.xml
```