# delete a object from the json file using a powershell

Tags: powershell

In this Question i want to accomplish is that i am trying to delete a specific object in the json file.
But while doing so i am experiencing some difficulties i tried to refer article [Iterate over JSON and remove JSON element in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794132/iterate-over-json-and-remove-json-element-in-powershell)

and implement the same but however it is deleting the entire element but i want to delete a specific object in the element not the entire element following are the required things

```
1. json file

    {
        "name":  "JourneyPack",
        "description":  "Details of the journey across india",
        "author":  "Sachin",
        "version":  "1.0.0",
        "main":  "main.js",
        "build":  {
                      "applicationID":  "desktop",
                      "Necessaryfiles":  [
                                    "main.js",
                                    "package.json",

                                ],
                      "Storage":  {
                                          "output":  "./reunited"
                                      },
                      "DeatilsOfJourney":  [
                                             {
                                                 "from":  "../Pune",
                                                 "to":  "../travel/Pune",
                                                 "filter":  [
                                                                "**/*
                                                            ]
                                             },
                                             {
                                                 "from":  "../Delhi",
                                                 "to":  "../travel/Delhi",
                                                 "filter":  [
                                                                "**/*"
                                                            ]
                                             },
                                             {
                                                 "from":  "../Jharkhand",
                                                 "to": "../travel/Jharkhand",
                                                 "filter":  [
                                                                "**/*"
                                                            ]
                                             },
                                         ],
                      "IOS":  {
                                  "category":  "desktop"
                              },
                      "Windows":  {
                                  "icon":  "images/desktopicons/icons.ico",
                                  "target":  [
                                                 "divfrieght"
                                             ],
                                  "publisherName":  [
                                                        "Sachin"
                                                    ]
                              },
                      "divfrieght":  {
                                   "PointClick":  true,
                                   "standaloneMachine":  true,
                                   "allowrise":  true,
                                   "allowinstdir":  true,
                                   "menu":  "JourneyPack"

                               }
                  },
        "private":  true,

    }
```

following is the tried code again this is that i have referred from [Iterate over JSON and remove JSON element in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794132/iterate-over-json-and-remove-json-element-in-powershell)
    2. tried code

```
    $inputFile  = '<THE FULL PATH AND FILENAME TO YOUR JSON FILE>'
    $outputFile = '<THE FULL PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE OUTPUT JSON FILE>'

    $apijson = Get-Content -Path $inputFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

    # for safety, first make a copy of the original .paths object
    $newPaths = $apijson.paths


    foreach ($element in $newPaths.PSObject.Properties) {
        $objName = $element.Name
        $objValue = $element.Value
        $objProperties = $objValue.PSObject.Properties
        foreach ($prop in $objProperties) {
            if ($prop.Value.'from' -eq 'Jharkhand') {
                $propName = $prop.Name
                $objProperties.Remove($propName)
                Write-Host "Removed object $objName -- $propName"
            }
        }
    }

    # now overwrite the $apijson.paths with this cleaned up version
    $apijson.paths = $newPaths

    # I assume you want to convert it back to a .JSON file??
    $apijson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $outputFile -Force
```

i want to delete the object where "from" is equal to "../Jharkhand/"

Desired Output

```
{
    "name":  "JourneyPack",
    "description":  "Details of the journey across india",
    "author":  "Sachin",
    "version":  "1.0.0",
    "main":  "main.js",
    "build":  {
                  "applicationID":  "desktop",
                  "Necessaryfiles":  [
                                "main.js",
                                "package.json",

                            ],
                  "Storage":  {
                                      "output":  "./reunited"
                                  },
                  "DeatilsOfJourney":  [
                                         {
                                             "from":  "../Pune",
                                             "to":  "../travel/Pune",
                                             "filter":  [
                                                            "**/*
                                                        ]
                                         },
                                         {
                                             "from":  "../Delhi",
                                             "to":  "../travel/Delhi",
                                             "filter":  [
                                                            "**/*"
                                                        ]
                                         },
                                     ],
                  "IOS":  {
                              "category":  "desktop"
                          },
                  "Windows":  {
                              "icon":  "images/desktopicons/icons.ico",
                              "target":  [
                                             "divfrieght"
                                         ],
                              "publisherName":  [
                                                    "Sachin"
                                                ]
                          },
                  "divfrieght":  {
                               "PointClick":  true,
                               "standaloneMachine":  true,
                               "allowrise":  true,
                               "allowinstdir":  true,
                               "menu":  "JourneyPack"

                           }
              },
    "private":  true,

}
```

if anyone could help that would be really helpful

Comment: The JSON file is broken. Please edit the question and add a working sample.

Comment: Did you tried the below code?

Answer (score 0):

".paths" property does not belong to you json file, so removed this part of your script.

```
# for safety, first make a copy of the original .paths object
$newPaths = $apijson.paths
```

Try this code:

```
$inputFile  = 'input.json'
$outputFile = 'output.json'

$apijson = Get-Content -Path $inputFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($element in $apijson.PSObject.Properties) {
    $objName = $element.Name
    $objValue = $element.Value
    $objProperties = $objValue.PSObject.Properties
    foreach ($prop in $objProperties) {
        # Your object lies in this array
        if ($prop.Name -eq 'DeatilsOfJourney') {   
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr = $prop.Value
            #Iterate over your array and find that object which you want to remove
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.count; $i++) {
                if ($arr[$i].'from' -eq '../Jharkhand')
                {
                    $arr.RemoveAt($i)
                    $i--
                }
            }
            $prop.Value = $arr
        }
    }
}

$apijson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $outputFile -Force
```